# c string array with null fails

Tags: c

A method that returns a string array. For some reason this method fails while accessing the string values specifically for the last `NULL` value.

```
static char **getList() {
    char **list = (char *[]){"ABC", "DEF", NULL};
    char **interests = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
    int i = 0;
    while(*list) {
        interests[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(*list));
        strcpy(interests[i++], *list);
        list++;
    }
    return interests;
}
```

Using

```
char **interests = getList();
while(*interests) {
    puts(*interests);
    interests++;
}
```

Attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Why create `list` the way you do? Why not a plain simple array of pointers, as in `char *list[] = { "ABC", "DEF", NULL };`? And if the array of strings will always be fixed, the strings never modified, you could use `static const char *list[] = ...;` and return that directly.

Comment: Also, don't forget that the length returned by `strlen` does *not* include the string null-terminator. Which means your `strcpy` calls will write out of bounds of your allocated memory, and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: And lastly note that you allocate `interests` as an array of three elements, and use it (when returned) as a null-terminated array, ***but*** you never actually copy the terminating `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Can you please put that as an answer, i read that it would cause issue because the array would be allocated on stack, fyi I'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using `strlen()`, the allocation lack for space for terminating null-character.
- The last element of what is pointed at by `interestes`, which should be `NULL`, is not initialized.

fixed version:

```
static char **getList() {
    char **list = (char *[]){"ABC", "DEF", NULL};
    char **interests = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
    int i = 0;
    while(*list) {
        interests[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(*list) + 1)); /* allocate one more */
        strcpy(interests[i++], *list);
        list++;
    }
    interests[i] = NULL; /* initialize the last element */
    return interests;
}
```

Comment: `strlen(*list) + 1`, this one more automatically puts null character, just a question, it was working without this extra character, mind help me understand this better. Thanks.

Comment: @AppDeveloper Accessing out-of-bounds invokes *undefined behavior*. You are unlucky because it happened to seem working well and they didn't gave you a chance to notice the bug.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. in comments above, it was suggested that since the array contents are not modified (it's true), I should use plain simple array of pointers, do you agree?

Comment: It depends on situration. Even if the contents are not modified, it is not guaranteed that the array or its contents will not be freed.  You must not pass pointers that are not returned by `malloc()` family to `free()`.

Comment: I'm the user of this function so provided that I can guarantee to free it, Should I return a plain simple array, trying to choose the best path here?

Comment: No. If you will free them, you must allocate them.

Comment: oh got it, `free` should be for `malloc` family only, can I simplify this example to return a plain array, just checking if this can be simplified.

Comment: Doing trial and error is good. If it is supported in your environment, AddressSanitizer is helpful to detecting memory management errors.

Answer (score 0):

You do some... *weird* things in the code you show. To begin with we have the `list` variable, which should be a simple and plain array instead.

And if the array or its contents should not be modified then you could even create an array whose life-time last the full run-time of the program, using `static`:

```
static const char * const *getList() {
    static const char * const list[] = { "ABC", "DEF", NULL };
    return list;
}
```

The declaration `const char * const list[]` declares `list` as an array (whose size will be deduced from the initialization) of constant pointers to constant characters. That is, the pointers inside `list` can't be modified, and the string contents itself can't be modified.

---

If you have other requirements, like being able to modify the strings, then you could still use the definition shown above in my answer, but create a new array to return.

There are a few improvements that can be made to the allocation and copying code as well. For example you could programatically get the size of the array `list`. I also recommend that you use a simple index loop instead of the pointer arithmetic loop you have now, and with the correct size of the `list` array the loop will include copying the terminating `NULL` as well.

All in all it could look something like

```
static char **getList() {
    static const char * const list[] = { "ABC", "DEF", NULL };

    // Get the number of elements in the array
    size_t list_size = sizeof list / sizeof list[0];

    // sizeof *interests is the size of each element we want to allocate
    // multiply it by the number of elements we need
    char **interests = malloc(sizeof *interests * list_size);

    // Do a deep copy of the strings from list
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list_size ++i) {
        if (list[i] == NULL) {
            interests[i] = NULL;
        } else {
            interests[i] = malloc(strlen(list[i]) + 1);  // +1 for the string terminator
            strcpy(interests[i], list[i]);

            // Or if your system have the strdup function (which is quite common)
            // interests[i] = strdup(list[i]);
        }
    }

    return interests;
}
```

If you don't need a deep copy, then the copying loop could be:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < list_size ++i) {
    interests[i] = list[i];
}
```